# PHP Array Search not working

Tags: php, arrays, search

Would anyone be able to help me out with why my array_search is not working in this PHP script I have written. I've been messing with this for days and cannot figure out this problem. I've tried moving array_search all over the place, inside the loop, outside the loop, and I'm getting the same results. I have tried searching for different array values, I've tried including my own functions for searching the array that i found online. I know the values are in the array because I have the arrays printed to a .txt file for debugging, and now I have no idea what to look for next. Any ideas?

```
   <?php 
//this variable tells us how many drupal nodes or 'paystub pages' we need to create
$nodeCount = 0;
$i = 0;
//needed for creating a drupal node
//for this code to work this script must be run from the root of the drupal installation
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
if ($handle = opendir('/var/www/html/pay.*********group.com/upload')) 
{
    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
       if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
       {
            $nodeCount++;
            //We convert the pdf documents into text documents and move put them in the converted folder
            $command = "pdftotext /var/www/html/pay.*********group.com/upload/" . $file . " /var/www/html/pay.*********group.com/upload/converted/" . $file . ".txt";
            //Execute the command above
            $output = exec($command);

        }   
    }       
    closedir($handle);      
}
//subtract two because the folders "array" and "converted" are included because PHP does not differentiate
//between folders and files
$nodeCount = $nodeCount - 2; 
echo "<br />";
echo "<b> $nodeCount pdf files converted </b>";
echo "<br />";
//open the directory
if ($handle2 = opendir('/var/www/html/pay.*********group.com/upload/converted')) 
{

    //check to see if we have reached the last file of our directory, if not stay in loop
    while (false !== ($currentText = readdir($handle2))) 
    {
        //filter out files named . and ..
       if ($currentText != "." && $currentText != "..") 
       {
            //Create a file for array to be printed to
            $createArray = fopen("/var/www/html/pay.*********group.com/upload/arrays/" . $currentText, "w+") or die ("Cannot find file to create array, ID 2");


            //read the file we are on from the loop into the array 
            $currArray = file("/var/www/html/pay.*********group.com/upload/converted/" . $currentText) or die ("Cannot find file to create array, ID 1");


            $ArrSearch = array_search("EMPLOYEE NO. ", $currArray);

            echo "<br />";
            echo "<b> $ArrSearch index found </b>";
            echo "<br />";

            //array_trim($currArray[$i]);           
            //var_dump($currArray[$i]);

            //print array to .txt file for debugging purposes
            $out = print_r($currArray, true);
            fwrite($createArray, $out);
            fclose($createArray);
            $i++;   

        }           
    }
}
?>
```

**edit: I fixed the code based on your conclusions, I updated the code here too. With the code above this is the out put I get while trying to convert 6 pdf files. Next to each index I should have an array index from each search**

```
6 pdf files converted 

index found 

index found 

index found 

index found 

index found 

index found
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you isolate a case of what you are searching for, what is in the file, and what doesn't get matched? That will work better than a huge chunk of code.

Comment: I think you're switched the needle and the haystack in your arguments... `$ArrSearch = array_search("EMPLOYEE NO. ", $currArray);`

Comment: @Brad You should add that as an answer

Comment: [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) has everything you need to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've switched the needle and the haystack in your arguments...

```
$ArrSearch = array_search("EMPLOYEE NO. ", $currArray);
```

*As requested, comment gone to answer*

*@meagar: wasn't sure if that was the problem, or if they exhausted that and are just trying anything after two days of frustration.*

Comment: I corrected that problem, the arrays are being printed to the proper .txt files just like they should be so I know I am creating an array. I also know that there is a space after the string I am searching for.

Comment: Is it possible to print_r the $ArrSearch so we can see what's being searched through? Then maybe point out which element you'd like to find, if it's not obvious?

Answer (score 1):

array_search(*needle*, *haystack*)

Don't you have that kinda wrong? (Sear for *needle* in *haystack*, not the other way around).

Comment: Fixed but still not working, take a look at the edited code in my original post

Answer (score 0):

$idx=  [array_search](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.array-search.php)($needle, $haystack);

you need to swap needle and haystack in your code

Comment: Fixed but still not working, take a look at the edited code in my original post

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're searching for lines that have the employee's number on them, for example "EMPLOYEE NO. 7" and so on. If you use `array_search("EMPLOYEE NO. ", $currArray)` it searches for rows that match **exactly** "EMPLOYEE NO. " so you're not getting any hits.

If you want to search for values that **start with** "EMPLOYEE NO. " you have to loop through the array and use `strpos()` to look for matches.

Comment: Nope, Im searching for the exact string EMPLOYEE NO.

Comment: Because whatever index employee no. is at, the actual employee number is always next in line.

Comment: I suggest that you loop through the array and print out every line with echo '"'.$row.'"'; to see what the exact wording of the line you're looking for is, and maybe even copy-paste the correct line to the code that searches it. Chances are that you're missing the exact wording.